# I followed this YY video: https://youtu.be/ZB3GLtQvgME?t=2003 but cannot 'chainlink node

Tags: postgresql, macos-mojave, chainlink

I followed this YY video: https://youtu.be/ZB3GLtQvgME?t=2003 but cannot 'chainlink node start'

Running 'chainlink help' is fine. Installation is Ok.
Everything before the video checks out.

Need help with 'chainlink node start' Error:

```
Jons-MacBook-Pro:.environments jon$ chainlink node start
2022-03-20T20:17:16.999-0700 [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 1.1.1 at commit 
4dba946389cbf063ce374eb832007c3367abe3dc                                  
SHA=4dba946389cbf063ce374eb832007c3367abe3dc Version=1.1.1 
logger=1.1.1@4dba946.RunNode 
2022-03-20T20:17:17.004-0700 [ERROR] Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: failed to 
open db: failed to connect to `host=/private/tmp user=jon database=`: server 
error (FATAL: unrecognized configuration parameter "?application_name" (SQLSTATE 
42704))                                  err=Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: 
failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=/private/tmp user=jon 
database=`: server error (FATAL: unrecognized configuration parameter "? 
application_name" (SQLSTATE 42704)) errVerbose=opening db: failed to open db: failed 
to connect to `host=/private/tmp user=jon database=`: server error (FATAL: 
unrecognized configuration parameter "?application_name" (SQLSTATE 42704))
Cannot boot Chainlink
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
/Users/jon/chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:52
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
/Users/jon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
/Users/jon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
/Users/jon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
/Users/jon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
/Users/jon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
/Users/jon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
main.Run
/Users/jon/chainlink/core/main.go:25
main.main.func1
/Users/jon/chainlink/core/main.go:18
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/recovery.ReportPanics
/Users/jon/chainlink/core/recovery/recover.go:17
main.main
/Users/jon/chainlink/core/main.go:17
runtime.main
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581 logger=1.1.1@4dba946 
Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to 
`host=/private/tmp user=jon database=`: server error (FATAL: unrecognized 
configuration parameter "?application_name" (SQLSTATE 42704))
Jons-MacBook-Pro:.environments jon$
```

Thank you!

This is the .env

```
ETH_URL=wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/fc5cd704c8d44cf3ac09d16d13687ab2
FEATURE_EXTERNAL_INITIATORS=true
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=42
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost:5432/kovan_demo?sslmode=disable
DATABASE_TIMEOUT=0
FEATURE_FLUX_MONITOR=true
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT=0
CHAINLINK_DEV=true
```

This is what happened if I use Docker:
failed to open db: failed to connect to
`host=localhost user=root database=kovan_demo`: dial error (dial
tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)

```
Jons-MacBook-Pro:.environments jon$ docker run -p 6688:6688 -v 
~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env 
smartcontract/chainlink:1.1.1 local n
2022-03-21T21:48:44.372Z [DEBUG] Initializing API credentials                       
cmd/client.go:636       file=/root/.chainlink/apicredentials 
2022-03-21T21:48:44.373Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 1.1.1 at 
commit 11788e23888b2d60554720faa237dabc62b1b8e7 
cmd/local_client.go:170 
SHA=11788e23888b2d60554720faa237dabc62b1b8e7 Version=1.1.1 
logger=RunNode 
2022-03-21T21:48:44.373Z [WARN]  Chainlink is running in 
DEVELOPMENT mode. This is a security risk if enabled in 
production. cmd/local_client.go:173 logger=RunNode 
opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to 
`host=localhost user=root database=kovan_demo`: dial error (dial 
tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)
Jons-MacBook-Pro:.environments jon$
```

Comment: Can you make this an issue on the Chainlink repo? Thanks!

Comment: Yes and just did that.

I also tried on Debian 11 and Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
After 'made install' is done:

`jon@jon-Ubuntu:~/chainlink$ chainlink help`
`chainlink: command not found`

Comment: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues/6273